# A line through the origin that bounds a proportion of points in a scatterplot

Tags: partitioning

Suppose I have a scatterplot in a box with 0 < x < x1 and y1 < y < y2.

Let 0 < prp < 1.

Is there an efficient way to find a line that passes through the origin, and that has prp proportion of the points below or on the line and (1-prp) proportion of the points above the line?

NOTE: If you are thinking of recommending quantile regression, don't. It addresses a different problem.

Comment: While I don't think this would be hard to do, what _is_ the problem that _you_ are trying to solve using this?

Comment: You are asking how to find quantiles of $y/x.$

Comment: @whuber I just noticed your comment. You're right. The slope of the line is the prp quantile of y/x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple 1D search will do the work

```
set.seed(0)
d = data.frame(x1=runif(100),x2=runif(100))
p = 0.3

obj_fun <- function(k){
  abs(sum(d$x2>k*d$x1) / nrow(d) - p)
}


plot(seq(0,10),sapply(seq(0,10),obj_fun),type='b')
grid()

plot(d)
grid()
abline(0,seq(0,10)[which.min(sapply(seq(0,10),obj_fun))])
```

Here is the objective function and the solution plot

[image]

Comment: Your solution is essentially brute force search. However, even when I increase the number of rows in the data frame to 1e5 and the search sequence to a length of 2001, so that it really gets close to 0, it's very fast. So this is a case where brute force search does the job! Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use the `quantile` function in `R` or at least suggest an efficient search method that will scale well?